# Qt - How to show tabs of tabified dockwidget at the top instead of the bottom

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qdockwidget

In Qt, you can tabify dockWidgets. If I do that, the tabs show on the bottom of the dockWidgets, as is shown in the left sketch. This is the behavior I get under Windows 7 with the latest Qt4 and PyQt4. How can I tell Qt to place the tabs on the dockWidgets top as shown 
in the right sketch?

```
default: tabs on bottom                 I want: tabs on top
+--------------------+                  +------+-----+
| dockWidget1        |                  | tab1 | tab2|-------+
|                    |                  |                    |
| tab1 | tab2|-------|                  | dockWidget1        |
+------+-----+                          +--------------------+
```

Comment: @hyde The OP was asking the **"tabification"** of the `QDockWidget` rather than QTabWidget. The functionality is not that trivial since it was defined in `QMainWindow`, and your link doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Tay2510 Oops, you're right. Finding the right place in docs for [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setTabPosition) can indeed take some searching. Well, good thing I didn't downvote myself (and the advice itself was sound, even if baseless for this question)...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call

`QMainWindow.setTabPosition (self, 
                             Qt.DockWidgetAreas areas, 
                             QTabWidget.TabPosition tabPosition)`

(Notice that this applies to the specific dock area, which means you can have different dock areas with various tab configurations.)

with the enumeration: `Qt.DockWidgetAreas` and `QTabWidget.TabPosition`:

```
#Qt.DockWidgetAreas
Constant                   Value
---------------------      -------
Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea       0x1
Qt.RightDockWidgetArea      0x2
Qt.TopDockWidgetArea        0x4
Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea     0x8
Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas       DockWidgetArea_Mask
Qt.NoDockWidgetArea         0


#QTabWidget.TabPosition
Constant          Value     Description
----------       -------    -----------
QTabWidget.North    0       The tabs are drawn above the pages.
QTabWidget.South    1       The tabs are drawn below the pages.
QTabWidget.West     2       The tabs are drawn to the left of the pages.
QTabWidget.East     3       The tabs are drawn to the right of the pages.
```

(Reference: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmainwindow.html#setTabPosition)

And here is the result:

[image]