# QDockWidget, place the tabs on top and insert text

Tags: python, pyqt

Are there any methods to make the tabs be placed on top? I think it's more suitable. And is there an easy way to name the tabs, maybe add a QLabel.

Below is a picture of how it looks now.

[image]

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751503/qt-how-to-show-tabs-of-tabified-dockwidget-at-the-top-instead-of-the-bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setTabPosition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setTabPosition) to put the tabs at the top for the relevant dock-areas:

```
mainwindow.setTabPosition(QtCore.Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas, QtGui.QTabWidget.North)
```

The tab text is taken from the window title, so it can be set like this:

```
dockwidget.setWindowTitle('Name')
```

or indirectly via the `QDockWidget` constructor:

```
dockwidget = QtGui.QDockWidget('Name', parent)
```